# Why does order of transforms matter in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, core-animation, transform

These two sequences give two different results in an image layer that this transform is applied to. I don't seem to get the reason why... Can anyone give an explanation for this?

```
/* first sequence of transformation */
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 180 * 30);
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 100, 0);

/* second sequence of transformation */
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 100, 0);
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 180 * 30);
```

Comment: If you translate first then the center of rotation will be different than if you translate afterwards.

Comment: Why? Shouldn't the `anchorPoint` remain unchanged? So it's in `(0.5, 0.5)`

Comment: My guess is that you would need to shift the anchorPoint to match the translate shift for the second case, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: The anchor point is determined by the `frame` of the view. When you transform a view the frame is unchanged and the view shifts inside the frame. So the rotation is still at (0.5, 0.5) of the frame but your view has been transformed.

Comment: Xcode has nothing to do with this. As David explains below in his excellent answer, matrix math isn't commutative. As for the anchorPoint, the anchorPoint of a layer is a convenience that changes the origin of the layer. Changing the anchor point and applying a translation to the transformation matrix both change the center point of the layer. Moving the position of the layer is usually easier to deal with, though, because the shift in the position of the layer is applied separately from translations to the transformation matrix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short (technical) answer: Because a transform is really just a matrix and when you concatenate two transforms, the two matrices are multiplied. Matrix multiplication isn't [commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property), meaning that ⨉ (A*B) is not the same as ⨉ (B*A). In other words, the order matters.

I have previously written about [combining translations and rotations](http://ronnqvi.st/translate-rotate-translate/) and about [the math behind transforms](http://ronnqvi.st/the-math-behind-transforms/) (i.e. an into to matrix mathematics). These two can be good resources if you want to learn more about how transforms work.

There is also a nice [project by Richard Turton](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/12/17/visual-tool-for-catransform3d/) on [GitHub](https://github.com/jrturton/3DTransformFun) for experimenting with transforms that can be very useful for grasping the concepts of how the order of different transforms impact the end result.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Worth noting that my project is for CATransform3D rather than CGAffineTransforms, but obviously the principles are the same.